# Saber si un numero es mayor o menor y verificar la edad

Tags: java

Debo crear un menu con dos opciones, la primera opción debería comprobar si un numero es mayor o menor a otro. La segunda opción debería poder verificar la edad de una persona, diciendo si es mayor o menor de edad.

El código que ha realizado es el siguiente:

```
    public class Prueba{
        //Metodo main
  
    public static void main(String[] args){  

                System.out.println("Escoja Una opcion:"); Escribir
                System.out.println("1 Mayor,menor");
                System.out.println("2 Verificador de edad");
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);  
                char valor = 'l';
                 char valorb = '2';
        if (valor == '1' ) 
            do{
                switch(valor){ // Metodo Switch
                    case 1: introducen 2 números enteros y el programa debe decir cual es mayor
                    {                       
                         int NumFa = entrada.nextInt();
                         System.out.println("Digite 2 nmeros enteros");
                         int NumFb = entrada.nextInt();
                         if(NumFa > NumFb){
                             System.out.println("Es Mayor");  
                         }
                         else {
                             if(NumFa < NumFb){
                                 System.out.println( "Es Menor");
                             }
                             else
                                 System.out.println( "son iguales");
                              
                         }   }
                    case 2: decir si es mayor o menor de edad
                    if (valor == '2' );
                      if (valorb == 2 ){
                         int mayor = 18;  
                         System.out.println("Digite Su edad");
                         entrada.next();
                         if (mayor >= 18){ 
                             System.out.println("Usted es mayor de edad");
                         }
                    
                         else{ 
                             System.out.println("Usted es menor de edad");
                             break;
                         }
                 
                           }
                           
            
                         
        }//fin del switch
        }while(valor != 1);
}//Fin Main 
    
       }//Fin Clase `
```

Comment: Este no es un duplicado. Este es un ejercicio básico para aprender `if`, `case` y `while` y el otro es un ejercicio que trata de `array`

Comment: Por favor aclara cuál es el problema del código. No podemos adivinar en qué parte deberíamos enfocar nuestra atención. Tampoco tiene sentido que reescribamos todo el programa.